# How can a React Native app be converted into a library that a native Android app can use?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have a bunch of views made in React Native that I want to use in a native android app.  To do this, the official [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#1-set-up-directory-structure) require me to change the entire project structure of the native app. I think this is to facilitate auto-linking. But I'm looking for an easier way that allows any native android app to use my views.

So, I tried to create an aar for the react native views (by changing `com.android.application` to `com.android.library` in app/build.gradle) but the code of native dependencies in /node_modules is not present in the final aar.

How can I include these native dependencies in the final aar? Or perhaps there is a better way to approach this. I would be grateful if someone with more experience could advise on this.